# How can i compare two values of two different for-each with xslt

Tags: arrays, xml, xslt

I am trying compare 2 variables with XSLT, have 2 different "for-each",

I want compare 2 values if this are equals add attribute disable for my radio.

so this is my template:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//array1">
  <xsl:variable name="NUMMOV_array1" select="NUMMOV" />

  <xsl:element name="input" >
  <xsl:attribute name="type">radio</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:for-each select="//array2">
      <xsl:variable name="NUMMOV_array2" select="NUMMOV" />
        <xsl:if test="NUMMOV_array2 = NUMMOV_array1"> <!-- HERE TRY COMAPRE-->
        <xsl:attribute name="disabled">disabled</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:element>

</xsl:for-each>
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on without a [mcve]. Certainly, you need to use a `$` prefix when referring to a variable.

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k i just want compare 2 values of 2 diferents array(xml), i cant do this. I question is posible make a variable and use this one into a for-each to compare?